# Qual a diferença nos métodos Refresh, Update, Repaint, Invalidate e no Application.ProcessMessages?

Tags: delphi

Qual a diferença entre os métodos:

1. [Refresh](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Refresh), de TControl;
2. [Update](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Update.html), de TControl;
3. [Repaint](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Invalidate.html), também deTControl; e,
4. [Invalidate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Invalidate.html), também de TControl;
5. Além do [Application.ProcessMessages](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_ProcessMessages.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Invalidate

O método **Invalidate** só marca o componente para ser pintado na próxima vez que a interface for atualizada. Ele não re-desenha o componente no momento que foi chamado.

### Update

Método que re-deseha o componente imediatamente, desde que ele já tenha sido invalidado, sem esperar pelo processamento das mensagens de re-desenhar pelo Windows. Gera consumo de tempo de processador pois vais parar todas as atividades da thread principal da aplicação para redesenhar.
Isto quer dizer que, se você tiver alterado algo que implique em mudança visual, e o componente não tiver sido Invalidado, depois do update a alteração pode não ser processsada.

### Repaint

O repaint força o componente a se re-desenhar imediatamente. Se a propriedade `ControlStyle` incluir `csOpaque`, o componente irá redesenhar-se, senão será executado o método `Invalidate` e logo depois o método `Update`

### Refresh

Segundo a documentação o `Refresh` executa o `Repaint`, e portanto fazem exatamente a mesa coisa, tanto que consta ainda que eles são intercambiáveis, isto é, tanto faz usar um ou o outro

### Application.ProcessMessages

Força a aplicação a processar as mensagem do Windows.

Quando a aplicação está realizando uma operação de alto custo de processamento, ou realizando um loop, a thread fica ocupada realizando aquela operação e não realiza o processamento de nenhuma mensagem do Windows para a aplicação, como um **clique em um componente**, **o pressionamento de uma tecla** ou neste caso a atualização dos componentes gráficos da aplicação.

Ser chamar o método `Invalidate` e logo depois `Application.ProcessMessages`, o windows irá tratar da mensagem do Invalidate e providenciar o re-desenho da janela ou do componente, juntamente com todas as demais mensagens.